# Run PHP script only first time even if 100.000 users access it at the same time

Tags: php, file

The title is pretty clear:

I have a PHP file and I want it to be executed only the first time even if 100.000 users try to access it at the same time.

Comment: What's the use case?  What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: Is that a joke? "I want it to be executed only the first time even if 100 users access it at the same time"... Please think before you ask.

Comment: With more than 3 answers, this question obviously has merit, no matter how short the question may be.  Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a lock file you write to the server, like:

```
if (!is_file("visited_once.txt"))
{
    //you're the one
    file_put_contents("visited_once.txt", "");
}
```

But maybe a database-solution would be more sophisticated as I'm not a 100% sure that the file solution works for 100.000 concurrent requests.

**create your table**

```
CREATE TABLE visited
(
    visit int NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (visit)
);
```

**do something like this on request**

```
try
{
    $db->query("INSERT INTO visited VALUES (0)");
    //you're the one
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    //nope! Already visited
}
```

This uses a unique key and relies on the database consistency.

Comment: I'm close to 100% certain that the file solution (as it is written) would choke if the script were hit by 100.000 concurrent requests. You might have better luck if you use [`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) and request an exclusive lock.

Comment: That's why I included the database example. I'm very much trusting MySQL in this more.

Comment: This is the best answer I think, but instead of try/catch I used if(mysql_errno()==1062)

Comment: Be careful with that, I would use a more general approach. What if something else goes wrong with your database (not reachable, corrupt tables... you know what I mean) and the error code changes?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(file_exists('check.txt')) exit;
file_put_contents('check.txt','1');
...your code...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something to a file as a flag that the script is being executed, and at the end of the script delete the file. At the start of the script check if the file exists.

e.g.:

```
$flag_file = 'flag.tmp';
if (file_exists($flag_file)) exit();
file_put_contents($flag_file, 1);

// rest of the script

unlink($flag_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you write to a txt file or MySQl table?  If so set a character in the text file or a field in the MySQL table to 0, and the first time the PHP script runs, set it to 1, and use an if statement:

```
RETRIEVE YOUR NUMBER VIA TXT OR MYSQL
$myVar = YOUR NUMBER;

if ($myVar > 0){
//don't run
}
else{
//run
}
```